# iOS 8 for iPhone/iWatch: is it better to use SpriteKit+UIKit or only standard UIKit to implement a spinning wheel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikit

I would like to create an iPhone/iWatch app featuring a spinning wheel. The spinning wheel will allow the user to control the behaviour of the app and should be **touchable**; in other words other than spinning (long touch) the wheel should be able to detect short touches.

To design the architecture of this App I have a doubt: should I use UIImage view subclasses only or should I use SpriteKit and mix it with UIKit?

[Example of spinning wheel](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Spinning_Ashoka_Chakra.gif).

Many thanks

Comment: I don't think iWatch *can* implement either `UIImageView` or `SpriteKit`, you need to use `WKInterfaceImage` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iPhone I've already done this by only using `UIKit`... And I didn't have any problem with it. So I would answer pure `UIKit`. On iWatch, I don't have the knowledge to answer you about this part.

You said you want to subclass `UIImageView`, but I don't think you want to do that. Instead, you should subclass `UIView` and manage `UIImageView` instances privately.

Also, if and only if you want to use `SpritKit` only for that component in your application, you should avoid using it because the less dependency you have, the more happy you are. But it's my personal thought about that.